# CSS Modules doesn't work, React 16

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-modules

I've installed css-loader and style-loader. Then I configured webpack.dev and webpack.prod.
I suppose there's a problem with webpack because component's syntax isn't complicated.
The component ignores styles.  Why?

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject"`enter code here`: "react-scripts eject"  
  }
```

webpack.config.dev.js

```
 test: /\.css$/,
 use: [
    require.resolve('style-loader'),
    {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
        },
    },
```

webpack.config.prod.js

```
test: /\.css$/,
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
    Object.assign(
    {
        fallback: {
            loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
            options: {
                hmr: false,
            },
        },
        use: [
        {
            loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
            options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
                minimize: true,
                sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
            },
        },
```

component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './addTask.css';

export default class AddTask extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.big}>
        this should be a big font
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

css for the component

```
.big {
    font-size: 111px;
}
```

Comment: Inspect the output in the DOM - is there a class name applied at all? If so, is it the mangled on you specified in the css module loader options, or is it just "big"?

Comment: Also, in dev mode, don't use the extracttextplugin, that loads your css into an external file. if you're not including that file in your html, it won't work. in dev mode let the style-loader inject your css via javascript

Comment: Check a working example in [webpack-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) project. Hope it helps!

Comment: Where is your compiled CSS going? Are you sure it's being loaded at all? Take a look at the webpack extract-text plugin.

Comment: I've inspect the output in the DOM - there's no class name applied to div at all. But what is the reason?

Comment: Did you try ejecting?

Comment: Yes, I've used 'yarn eject' so now I can configure hidden files.
There's a good point that I don't know where my compiled css is going.

Comment: i have similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64738605/css-loadel-how-to-correct-use-with-webpack-5

Answer (score 9):

rename

```
addTask.css
```

to

```
addTask.module.css
```

and change the import to

```
import styles from './addTask.module.css'
```

Comment: this works for me. fyi im using 16.7 version of react. all of the examples in editing your webpack.config.js is useless now cause i think its built in already

Answer (score 3):

In order for react to understand your css file is a css-module, you need to add the suffix `.module` to the file name while using a react-script version newer than `2.0.0`.

Simply rename `addTask.css` to `addTask.module.css` and change the import to:

```
import styles from './addTask.module.css'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Was using a git to track the files.

Before running `npm run eject` to edit in the webpack.config file I have added and commit the react package into the repo.

Then I run `npm run eject` and added above mentioned changes. and Again I restart the npm, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following syntax for your webpack config file?

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#configuration

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader

```
   module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            modules: true,
                            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to paste it below the " test: /.css$/, ". It helped me.

```
use: [
                  require.resolve('style-loader'),
                  {
                      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                      options: {
                          importLoaders: 1,
                          modules:true,
                          localIdentName:'[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                      },
                  },
                  {
                      loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                      options: {
                          // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                          // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                          ident: 'postcss',
                          plugins: () => [
                              require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                              autoprefixer({
                                  browsers: [
                                      '>1%',
                                      'last 4 versions',
                                      'Firefox ESR',
                                      'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                                  ],
                                  flexbox: 'no-2009',
                              }),
                          ],
                      },
                  },
              ],
```